# History sniffing with HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-history

I have an assignment where I have to create a simple HTML website that is supposed to do some history sniffing. The goal, is for the site to be able to tell if a user has previously visited a specific URL (say cnn.com).

I have been looking into some implementations into how to do his with javascript, but I have seen in various readings, and posts that history sniffing is no longer allowed in browsers.

If browsers allowed for this, I would have just used javascript to go through browser history and see if the desired site was visited.

In summary, my question is whether or not this simple assignment is something that can actually be done.

Comment: The answer is in the second paragraph of the question. Browsers have taken measures to prevent that sort of privacy invasion.

Comment: This is a trick assignment.

Comment: Browsers don't have this kind of functionality. Pages can't even peek at the previous history of their own current session.

Comment: Yeah seems like it is. Looks like Ill be having an interesting conversation wit my professor. Thanks though! Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Once upon time it was possible. Basically checking a link's default font color was able to give you a hint about it. but i think ie6 was the last of that misuse. (gosh, i was thinking ie6 was garbage :P)